# Statistical Significance?

Tags: statistical-significance, categorical-data, survey

I'm wondering if there is some sort of statistical significance test that would suit my data, or whether I have to depend solely on descriptive statistics. Here's what I've got:
Thirty six students were given an independent living skills questionnaire (yes or no answers), and then 2 of their chosen references filled out an independent living skills questionnaire (also yes/no answer, not the same questionnaire but extremely similar, just a couple differences in items). 
Two main question: 
The 1st is this...is there any way to compare the mean of student scores to the mean of the reference scores, assuming I drop the questions that were added to one form of the questionnaire to make them equal? 
The 2nd is this...could I do an independent t-test with the two groups of references? Technically they are not "groups" of references...it's just that one group is the first reference listed for each student and the second group is the second reference listed for each student.

Basically I'm just trying to figure out if there's a more meaningful way to convey these results than just the use of descriptives.

Thanks very much.

Comment: The two groups of references are not independent of each other since they're paired on student.